# How can I pass secrets in a Terraform resource?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

context: I'm adding a new resource `foo` to Terraform provider.

The interesting detail about `foo` is that the corresponding `POST` API request requires to pass 0 or more secret values (best represented as a `TypeMap`) and then these secrets are pretty much useless (both `READ`, `UPDATE` work without it) and I think it doesn't really makes sense to store these secrets in Terraform configuration / state which is why I'd like to set this `secrets_map` attribute to either `null` or empty map.

So I started with this definition for this resource:

```
"secrets_map": {
    Type: schema.TypeMap,
    Elem: &schema.Schema{
        Type: schema.TypeString,
    },
    Sensitive:   true,
    Optional:    true,
    Computed:    true,
    ForceNew:    false,
},
```

I picked `Optional + Computed` over `Required: true` because `d.Set("secrets_map", make(map[string]string))` was failing but I'm still running into some issues. Is there an example of such a setup?

My ideal workflow would be:

1. Import works doesn't require user to set `secrets_map` at all.
2. Initially a user sets `secrets_map` attribute to allow Terraform Provider to read secrets to set them in `CREATE` request and then `terraform apply / plan` to ensure everything is in sync and then a user deletes this block from their TF configuration file, runs `terraform apply` to update `secrets_map` in TF state and then there're no changes when someone runs `terraform plan`.
3. I also figured `DiffSurpressFunc` doesn't really work for `TypeMap` which is a bummer: [Is it possible to use DiffSuppressFunc for a TypeMap in Terraform SDK v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72192632/is-it-possible-to-use-diffsuppressfunc-for-a-typemap-in-terraform-sdk-v2)

My newest idea is to set `secrets_map` to `null` in `fooRead()`.

Comment: This sounds like just `Optional`, and not `Optional` and `Computed` to me. I believe you also have objective 1 already satisfied with your current schema attributes. Have you considered setting this attribute to `null` at the end of the `Create` function if you want to discard it after initial success? Primary issue there would be incorrect state drift if the developer does not remove this from the config afterwards.

Comment: > Primary issue there would be incorrect state drift if the developer does not remove this from the config afterwards. -- just to clarify, the workflow would be `terraform apply` to create a resource, delete `secrets_map` from TF configuration and _then_ `terraform plan` that should show no drift?

> Have you considered setting this attribute to null at the end of the Create function
are you talking about `d.Set("secrets_map", null)` -> it looked like it doesn't actually set to nil but rather an empty value or something (or doesn't work well without _Computed_).

Comment: for example, see https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/issues/90#issuecomment-606079447

Comment: another idea I had is just not to have secrets_map attribute in a schema at all and just read the value for it in runtime to avoid d.Set(secrets_map, ) altogether

Comment: > not to have secrets_map attribute in a schema at all -- that doesn't work unfortunately -- An argument named "secrets_map" is not expected here.

Comment: 1. Yes I think that is feasible with that route. 2. I was dumb and meant `nil`, but seems like you translated that correctly. So I guess that idea is a dead end unless the "empty" works out fine(?). 3. Wow that is an interesting GH issue link.

Comment: I'll test again but I feel like unless we specify that attribute as computed TF SDK doesn't like these hardcoded assignments (d.Set()) and display warning messages in the logs.